# Red Squiggly Lines in VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, editor

My Visual Studio code editor keeps underlining my code incorrectly and I don't know how to stop it.

Here is an example of my JavaScript being squiggled:
[image]

I have tried installing prettier, eslint but it does nothing to solve this.

How can I stop these squiggly lines from appearing incorrectly?  I want them IF they are correct.

If I click on the problems tab, it shows this:
[image]

Comment: Click onto the problems tab in the bottom pane there (far left tab), it should contain more info on what's throwing the errors and what exactly it sees as an error. Post a screenshot of that pane if it's still not clear.

Comment: I was able to update with the output.  None of this output seems right.

Comment: Based on a little bit of research, these look like they are possibly coming from the [StandardJS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenxsan.vscode-standardjs).

Comment: That is, if you have that installed of course. These error messages almost always come from an installed extension (in my experience).

Comment: these are linter warnings, disable your linter or change it settings to only warn you of stuff you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!  Thanks to zscoop98's answer, I was able to find [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenxsan.vscode-standardjs) which showed there exists an option `standard.enable` in settings.json that, after setting that from `true` to `false`, it solved the issue and there are no longer these annoying red squiggly lines.

Answer (score 2):

And you can uninstall ESLint extension in vs code to get rid of red lines.You can search ESLint extension in extions folder of vscode