# React Native Javascript syntax with red underlined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just opened my react native apps, and then my js file turned out like this.
But when i run the apps, it worked perfectly.

tried to disable prettier but still, and tried to quick fix but still same.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Red Squiggly Lines in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419399/red-squiggly-lines-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

this came from eslint click `Quick Fix` or run this command:

```bash
npx eslint --ext=.js,.jsx --fix
```